# Sending data of variable length to SQL table from PHP, is there a better way?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a JSON string coming into a PHP file from JS/AJAX.  The number of entries is dynamic, ranging from 6 to 30.

I populate an array as follow

```
$myarray = array();
$dataLength= count($decodedJSON['make'][0]['model'][0]['color']);
for ($x = 0; $x < $dataLength*2; $x+=2) {
    $myarray[$x] = $decodedJSON['make'][0]['model'][0]['color'][$x/2]['int'];
    $myarray[$x+1] = $decodedJSON['make'][0]['model'][0]['color'][$x/2]['ext'];
}
for ($x = $dataLength*2; $x < 30; $x++) {
    $myarray[$x] = 0;
}
```

So this basically gives me an array that is end-padded with zeros with my data at the front.

Now, I want to insert this into my SQL table that has that maximum number of column

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cars VALUES ( '$dataLength', '$myarray[0]', '$myarray[1]', '$myarray[2]', '$myarray[3]', '$myarray[4]', '$myarray[5]', '$myarray[6]', '$myarray[7]', '$myarray[8]', '$myarray[9]', '$myarray[10]', '$myarray[11]', '$myarray[12]', '$myarray[13]', '$myarray[14]', '$myarray[15]', '$myarray[16]', '$myarray[17]', '$myarray[18]', '$myarray[19]', '$myarray[20]', '$myarray[21]', '$myarray[22]', '$myarray[23]', '$myarray[24]', '$myarray[25]', '$myarray[26]', '$myarray[27]', '$myarray[28]', '$myarray[29]', 42)";
```

but I'm thinking there must be a better way???

Thanks for any help, 
HSC.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't fill the array with zeros when you declare it; then you can save the last loop:

```
$myarray =array_fill(0,30,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PDO` you could simple things up like this:

```
try { 
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass,  array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Could not connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}   

$sql = 'INSERT INTO cars VALUES ('.implode(',',array_fill(0,30,'?')).')';
$values = array_fill(0,30, null);   
/** populate array with data here ... **/

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
try {
    $stmt->execute($values);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

A sidenote here, it would be better if you could determine which columns are required to do the insert, you could alter your JSON to match the column with the value. This way you would prevent the overhead of always have to define the 30 columns and you just could assign a default value the column